# How to add canvas and secure canvas URL in Facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I am trying to develop Facebook tutorial "Friends Smash" but I got stuck in a big problem it does not shows any option for adding canvas and secure canvas URL in

> Settings >> Add Platform >> Website

I am getting below options

[image]

How can I add canvas and secure canvas URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas and secure canvas URLs are only relevant for applications that are on Facebook. Your application (if you're on the "website" platform) doesn't have any use for canvas URLs.

An exerpt from [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#canvas) talking about canvas applications:

> Apps on Facebook are loaded into the Canvas section of the Canvas
>   Page. The Canvas is quite literally a blank canvas within Facebook on
>   which to run your app. You populate the Canvas by providing a Canvas
>   URL that contains the HTML, JavaScript and CSS that make up your app.
>   When a person using your app requests the Canvas Page, we load the
>   Canvas URL within an iframe on that page. This results in your app
>   being displayed within the standard Facebook chrome.

Comment: When i am trying to open http://apps.facebook.com/mygame it shows me error to add canvas and secure canvas url...

Comment: If you want your application to run within Facebook you'll have to add "Facebook" as a platform to your application.

Comment: i added facebook platform and canvas url as domain:localhost canvas url:http://localhost/fb secure canvas url as blank....i am getting blank page if i use apps.facebook.com/mygame and i am getting error as  API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration. if i use localhost/fb

Comment: No more link you provided for `#canvas`. I has redirection somewhere

Comment: @Lix could I put iframe inside code of my Secure Canvas Url? I just need to load all URLs that users insert into my app inside Facebook Canvas(if they are secure of course),  so that's the only thing that works for me, but i wonder if Facebook allows iframe for app's secure canvas url.

Answer (score 0):

Click add Platform and then you can add your canvas url and secure canvas url.

Comment: what are the canvas url and canvas secure url? where to get those?