# Accepting an app request from a phonegap app (no canvas)

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova

I have a phonegap app that I plan to launch on iOS and Android. I am using the facebook-connect plugin to successfully authorize users and send app requests. However, I am running into an issue when trying to accept those requests.

Clicking on the app request as a test-user in facebook takes me to a canvas url page that my app does not have because it is a mobile app, and not a canvas app or game.

I am hoping that when I add my iOS and Android platform info to the facebook app settings it will identify my app as a mobile app and fix the url, but I don't really know why or how :)

Also, feels like a catch 22 because I need to publish my apps in the app stores to get that platform info so I can test whether my app can handle app requests...

I read on a similar post about accepting requests from a web app that the best solution was to create a dummy canvas url just to redirect to the mobile app, but I was hoping there is a better option for a native phonegap app.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I understand that I do not require a canvas and am trying to avoid that. I do not have any platform added at the moment since I don't have the app store details yet. I think I made some progress thanks to Tech_Intelliswift's link below.

I went into the Advanced tab in the app settings on facebook and clicked "yes" for "Native or desktop app?" and now when I try to accept the request logged in as a test-user I get:

Misconfigured App
Sorry, [App] hasn't been approved for display in App Center.

I thought apps were pre-approved for test-users, maybe it's still a canvas issue?

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to WizKid's comment, I now see that my app must be a game to use app requests. Say that is the case, how do I configure my phonegap app as a facebook game to leverage app requests without a canvas?

Comment: How to invite people you can read about here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app . If you are not a game and have a canvas version you can not use requests

Comment: what exactly was your solution? how can you define an app as game?

Answer (score 0):

Canvas and secure canvas URLs are only relevant for applications that are on Facebook, for phonegap application you wont require canvas url, check whether you are configuring facebook settings for the application properly

Refer @Lix answer in this link [How to add canvas and secure canvas URL in Facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362242/how-to-add-canvas-and-secure-canvas-url-in-facebook-application)